# grab and resizing issue for fibonacci retracement

Tags: python, tkinter

i am trying to do a replica of metatrader fibonacci retracement and i am stock on resize and grab issue where i can open fibo with levels and resize but as soon as I touch the center, which is the grab, it always stays in grab, it doesn't do any more resizing.

```
import tkinter as tk

class FibonacciRetracementApp:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Fibonacci Retracement")
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.master, width=600, height=400, bg="white")
        self.canvas.pack(expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.BOTH)
        self.points = []
        self.lines = []
        self.center_point = None
        self.second_set_drawn = False
        self.resizing = False
        self.resizing_point = None
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.create_point)
        self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.on_motion)
        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.release_button)

    def create_point(self, event):
        x, y = event.x, event.y
        if self.second_set_drawn:
            self.check_for_resizing(x, y)
            return
        self.points.append((x, y))
        if len(self.points) == 2:
            if not self.second_set_drawn:
                self.draw_fibonacci_retracement()
                self.second_set_drawn = True
                self.canvas.delete("point")

    def check_for_resizing(self, x, y):
        if len(self.points) == 2:
            if self.center_point is None:
                self.add_center_point()

            x1, y1 = self.points[0]
            x2, y2 = self.points[1]

            # Check if the cursor is near the first resize corner
            if self.is_near_resize_corner(x, y, x1, y1):
                self.resizing = True
                self.resizing_point = 0

            # Check if the cursor is near the second resize corner
            elif self.is_near_resize_corner(x, y, x2, y2):
                self.resizing = True
                self.resizing_point = 1

    def is_near_resize_corner(self, x, y, corner_x, corner_y):
        return (corner_x - 5 <= x <= corner_x + 5) and (corner_y - 5 <= y <= corner_y + 5)

    def add_center_point(self):
        x1, y1 = self.points[0]
        x2, y2 = self.points[1]
        center_x = (x1 + x2) // 2
        center_y = (y1 + y2) // 2
        self.center_point = (center_x, center_y)

    def move_center_point(self, event):
        if self.center_point is not None:
            x, y = event.x, event.y
            dx = x - self.center_point[0]
            dy = y - self.center_point[1]
            self.canvas.move("blue_line", dx, dy)
            self.center_point = (x, y)

    def move_existing_point(self, x, y):
        if self.resizing_point is not None:
            self.points[self.resizing_point] = (x, y)
            self.update_fibonacci_retracement()

    def draw_fibonacci_retracement(self):
        x1, y1 = self.points[0]
        x2, y2 = self.points[1]
        retracement_levels = [0, 0.236, 0.382, 0.5, 0.618, 0.786, 1.0]
        for level in retracement_levels:
            y_level = y1 + level * (y2 - y1)
            line = self.canvas.create_line(x1, y_level, x2, y_level, fill="blue", dash=(4, 2), tags="blue_line")
            self.lines.append(line)

    def update_fibonacci_retracement(self):
        if len(self.points) == 2:
            x1, y1 = self.points[0]
            x2, y2 = self.points[1]
            self.canvas.delete("blue_line")
            retracement_levels = [0, 0.236, 0.382, 0.5, 0.618, 0.786, 1.0]
            for level in retracement_levels:
                y_level = y1 + level * (y2 - y1)
                line = self.canvas.create_line(x1, y_level, x2, y_level, fill="blue", dash=(4, 2), tags="blue_line")
                self.lines.append(line)

    def on_motion(self, event):
        if self.resizing:
            x, y = event.x, event.y
            self.move_existing_point(x, y)
        elif self.center_point is not None:
            self.move_center_point(event)

    def release_button(self, event):
        self.resizing = False
        self.resizing_point = None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = FibonacciRetracementApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

I'm trying to get grab and resizing logic to work without problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to update `self.points` after moving and `self.center_point` after resizing.

```
def move_center_point(self, event):
    if self.center_point is not None:
        x, y = event.x, event.y
        dx = x - self.center_point[0]
        dy = y - self.center_point[1]
        self.canvas.move("blue_line", dx, dy)
        self.center_point = (x, y)
        ### update self.points
        self.points[0] = (self.points[0][0]+dx, self.points[0][1]+dy)
        self.points[1] = (self.points[1][0]+dx, self.points[1][1]+dy)

def move_existing_point(self, x, y):
    if self.resizing_point is not None:
        self.points[self.resizing_point] = (x, y)
        self.update_fibonacci_retracement()
        ### update center point
        x1, y1 = self.points[0]
        x2, y2 = self.points[1]
        self.center_point = ((x1 + x2) // 2, (y1 + y2) // 2)
```